# Take number of person from AddressBook and compare it to Parse DB

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, abaddressbook, twitter-digits

Got caught a problem today.

I am using DigitsKit + Parse, DigitsKit for User real-Validation and Parse as useful framework to make easy sinUp, login etc for users and me as well.

Here is how it works:

1. Users type their PhoneNumber and Password in textField
2. After that DigitsKit validate with SMS and short code, that user
   is real, sms came to USER and he/she type it in validation
   textField. IF everything is okay -> username and password store in
   Parse DB as PFUser.

   username(in ParseDB) = user'sMobilePhone(in
   textField)
3. Than after signUp and login user push the button 'FindFriends' on the new view and here should be the friend-search system, but I have a problem here... Look the case for Controller below please:

   ```
   import UIKit
   import SwiftAddressBook
   import AddressBook
   import Parse

   class FriendsViewController: UIViewController {
   let status : ABAuthorizationStatus = SwiftAddressBook.authorizationStatus()

       var addrssbk : ABAddressBook!
   var addressBook: SwiftAddressBook? = swiftAddressBook


   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       GetContactNumbers()
             }



   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


   }






   func createAddressBook() -> Bool {
   if self.addressBook != nil {
       return true
   }
   var err : Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
   let addrssbk : ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &err).takeRetainedValue()
   if addrssbk == nil {
       println(err)
       self.addressBook = nil
       return false
   }
   self.addrssbk = addrssbk
   return true
   }

      func determineStatus() -> Bool {
   let status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
   switch status {
   case .Authorized:
       return self.createAddressBook()
   case .NotDetermined:
       var ok = false
       ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(nil) {
           (granted:Bool, err:CFError!) in
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
               if granted {
                   ok = self.createAddressBook()
               }
           }
       }
       if ok == true {
           return true
       }
       self.addressBook = nil
       return false
   case .Restricted:
       self.addressBook = nil
       return false
   case .Denied:
       self.addressBook = nil
       return false
   }
   }


   func GetContactNumbers() {

   swiftAddressBook?.requestAccessWithCompletion({ (success, error) -> Void in
       if success {
           if let people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
               for person in people {
                   if let numbers = person.phoneNumbers {
                           let names = person.compositeName
                      NSLog("%@", numbers.map( {$0.value} ))
                      NSLog("%@", names!)



                      if let query = PFUser.query() {

                          query.whereKey("username", equalTo: "\(person.phoneNumbers)")
                          var friends = query.findObjects()
                          println(friends)
                       }



                   //the value entry of the multivalue struct contains the data

                   }
               }
           }
           //do something with swiftAddressBook

       }else {
           //no success. Optionally evaluate error
        }
   })


   }



   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }



   }
   ```

I can't take the each phoneNumber and compare it to user's name in ParseDB, any suggestions how should i don this? Or any hits/solutions?

P.S, I have kind'a troubles with arrays, dictionaries and other array/key-value types of data and loops as well, so any help will be perfect

Comment: may be problem is because in ParseDB format of number is different with AddressBook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with using map and stringFormation:

```
   func GetContactNumbers() {

        let query = PFUser.query()

        swiftAddressBook?.requestAccessWithCompletion({ (success, error) -> Void in
            if success {
                if let people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
                    for person in people {
                        if let numbers = person.phoneNumbers {
                           let names = person.compositeName
                            let formatednumbers = numbers.map { $0.value.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet).reduce("", combine: {$0+$1})}
//                            NSLog("%@", numbers.map( {$0.value} ))
                            NSLog("%@", names!)
                            println(formatednumbers)
                            query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: "\(formatednumbers)")

                            if let friends = query!.findObjects() {
                                println(friends)

                            }





                        //the value entry of the multivalue struct contains the data

                        }
                    }
                }
                //do something with swiftAddressBook

            }else {
                //no success. Optionally evaluate error
             }
        })


    }
```